# Configuring Django Sentry's Server Name

Tags: django, sentry

I've just got started with [Sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/sentry), which is lovely. I've got about 10 different sites, some of which live on the same servers, which have names like web12.example.com. These server names get passed through to Sentry's interface, so I can filter by which server the errors have come from. Filtering by server isn't particularly useful - what would be useful is filtering by site.

Is there a way to change the server name to not be the actual server name, but (for example) the domain name that the error came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentry already does what I wanted, with the (apparently undocumented) `SENTRY_SITE` settings. I just set the following in my `settings.py` file:

```
SENTRY_SITE = u'My Site Name'
```

and I can filter on it from the filters list on the right-hand side of the Sentry interface.

Server name isn't intended for this purpose (presumably for people with large setups, it's useful to see if lots of errors are coming from a particularly server, which may be indicative of configuration issues), this is what the site filter is for.

Answer (score 0):

Now they have an [option](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/options/) to set this:

```
sentry_sdk.init(
    <endpoint>,
    server_name='a_name_to_distinguish_instance',
    ...
)
```

In web UI, one may use `server_name` tag to filter issues for an instance configured this way.